# Constraints on protocol crashes code execution

Tags: swift

I got this code:

```
import UIKit

protocol Test where Self: UIView {
    func printAnything()
}

class MyView: UIView, Test {
    func printAnything() {
        print("Anything")
    }
}

let myView: Test = MyView()
myView.printAnything()
```

The constraints are: `where Self: UIView`

When you paste this in playground, it crashes with this error at runtime:

> error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1,
>   address=0x0).

Removing the constraints, does remove the runtime error and does print "Anything". Why do the added constraints crashes on runtime?

Running XCode 9.3 Swift 4.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to constrain this to an Objective-C type, the protocol needs to be `@objc`:

```
@objc protocol Test where Self: UIView {
    func printAnything()
}
```

This is a known defect: [SR-7068](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-7068).

Comment: Oddly the error also goes away if you change the protocol declaration to `protocol Test: AnyObject where Self: UIView {`

Comment: @rmaddy Do you get a warning about the redundant conformance? The problem went away for me if I added `: class`, but it added a warning.

Comment: In an Xcode 9.2 playground I did not get a warning about the redundant conformance which I did expect to get. No warning using `class` instead of `AnyObject` either.